# Java Stream: Parsing Strings inside the reduce() operation

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I have a stream of strings:

```
Stream<String> st = Arrays.stream(new String[]{"10", "20", "30",  "40", "50"});
```

I want to convert them to integer and sum them up using the `reduce` method. I'm using reduce in the following format:

```
int result = st.reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + Integer.parseInt(b));
```

I get this error:

```
no suitable method found for reduce(int, (a, b) -> a + [...]nt(b))
```

any hint about how can I rewrite the reduce method to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a *combiner* function as the third argument to make it work:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(new String[]{"10", "20", "30",  "40", "50"})
            .reduce(0, (a, b)-> a + Integer.parseInt(b), Integer::sum);
```

Otherwise you're getting the different flavor of `reduce()` which is capable of produce the result of the same type as the type of elements in the stream.

And you don't need `reduce()`, the better way:

```
int sum = Stream.of("10", "20", "30",  "40", "50")
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
```

Comment: Also `Stream.of("10", "20", "30",  "40", "50")` to make it shorter.

Comment: @alexander-ivanchenko, thanks, BTW, why `Integer::sum` is needed?

Comment: @vortex Because you are getting this overloaded version [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) - *identity* of type `T` and result of also of type `T`, meanwhile you require this  [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) which provides a way to grab the elements of type `T` from the stream and produce the result of type `U`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `reduce()`, I'd break it into two steps: Convert the strings to ints (As an `IntStream`), and then sum them:

```java
Stream.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50").mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert them to integer and sum them up using the reduce method. I am using reduce in the following format:

When converting to an `IntStream` via `Integer::parseInt` the `reduce` method takes a form of an `int` starting value and an `IntBinaryOperator`. So the following will work.

```
String[] data ={"10", "20", "30",  "40", "50"};
int sum = Arrays.stream(data)
           .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).reduce(0, (a,b)->(a+b));
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
150
```

And for your edification (and future requirements) you can do it like so.

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(data).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
150
```